# TwiMLResponse with dial verb in java

Tags: java, twilio

I am trying to make a call. I am able to successfully make the call to the phone, but it's saying: "Sorry, some application error occurred". It could be an issue in the response XML.

Below is the code to make the call:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/makeCall", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody
    String makeCall(@RequestBody TwilRequest twilRequest, HttpServletRequest request) {

   ....
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("From", CallerID);
    params.put("To", addPulsIfNot(twilRequest.getToPhone()));
    params.put(
    "Url", "http://example.com/ws/twil/voiceResponse?phone=9198989...");

     .....
    }
```

Below is the response service that invoke and return response xml:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/voiceResponse", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String voiceResponse(HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    TwiMLResponse twiml = new TwiMLResponse();
      Dial dial = new Dial(addPulsIfNot(phone));
      try {
        dial.append(client);
        twiml.append(dial);
      } catch (TwiMLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
     response.setContentType("Application/xml");
     return twiml.toXML();
    }
```

I am not sure what is wrong. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you running this locally or on a server? Can you check the [Monitor](https://www.twilio.com/user/account/monitor/alerts) section of the Twilio dashboard and see what the error actually is?

Comment: Thanks philnash, Now its working the issue was method =RequestMethod.GET, its should be POST. It could be help others.

Comment: Aha! You can actually set the [method you want to use in the your request to the API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#post-parameters-optional). We do, however, recommend using POST. Glad it's all working for you now.

Answer (score 3):

Issue was method `=RequestMethod.GET`, should be POST.

You can specificy the method you wish to use in your [API request](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#post-parameters-optional). POST is recommended and is the default.

In this example Twilio will POST to `http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml` to fetch TwiML to handle the call:

```
// Build a filter for the CallList
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Url", "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml"));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("To", "client:tommy"));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("From", "+14158675309"));
```

But here Twilio will send a GET request to `http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml` to fetch TwiML to handle the call.

```
// Build a filter for the CallList
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Url", "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml"));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("To", "+14155551212"));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("SendDigits", "1234#"));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("From", "+18668675309"));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Method", "GET"));
```

Comment: Hey Megan, can you please help with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54157444/real-time-transcription-twilio-agent-conference)