# Real time transcription | Twilio Agent Conference

Tags: twilio

I am referrring to the demo Kris gives [here](https://youtu.be/Am74WU1zENA?t=727), especially the separate active transcriptions that show up for Stuart and Kris. I am familiar with conference, gather, dial but I am not able to replicate the entire architecture. I am interested in placing 2 people on a conference and somehow receive their transcriptions in real-time as the wonderful demo shows. I have enabled `Agent-Conference` tried the `coach` feature, but still can't figure out how to use Gather with conference participants. If I put a participant in Gather mode the other participant can't hear her. Can anyone please throw some pointers, I am sure I'm missing something basic here.

Till now I have tried:

```
Call call1 = Call.creator(new PhoneNumber("MyNumber"), new PhoneNumber("VerifiedTwilioNumber"),
                new URI("https://mywebsite/gather.xml")).create();
```

https://mywebsite/gather.xml returns

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
<Gather input="speech" speechTimeout="auto" partialResultCallback="https://mywebsite/gather_twilio_webhook_servlet">
    </Gather>
</Response>
```

Using this I speak to no-one but whatever I speak gets shown real-time on my gather_twilio_webhook_servlet.

I have also made conferences using :

```
Call call1 = Call.creator(new PhoneNumber("MyNumber"), new PhoneNumber("VerifiedTwilioNumber"),
                        new URI("https://mywebsite/conf.xml")).create();
Call call2 = Call.creator(new PhoneNumber("MyFriendsNumber"), new PhoneNumber("VerifiedTwilioNumber"),
                        new URI("https://mywebsite/conf.xml")).create();
```

https://mywebsite/conf.xml returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Dial>
    <Conference startConferenceOnEnter="true" endConferenceOnExit="true">Room 123</Conference>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

I am trying combinations thereof but not able to find a documentation to replicate Kris's exact use case. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Update, more trials:

If I try something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Gather input="speech" speechTimeout="auto" partialResultCallback="https://mywebsite/gather_twilio_webhook_servlet" language="en-IN">
        <Dial>
            <Conference record="record-from-start">room-2</Conference>
        </Dial>
    </Gather>
</Response>
```

I get `ErrorCode "13320" Msg    "Gather: Invalid nested verb"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The demo Kris showed is not available right now to use publicly. I know it was a while back, but bringing it to market was not as high a priority as other things we have launched since.

If you are interested in features like this, I recommend you [get in touch with sales](https://www.twilio.com/help/sales) and discuss what you would like to use it for.

Comment: Hi Phil, thanks for the response! I am awaiting word back from sales, would love to talk to them when they repond meanwhile do you know sales engineer you can hopefully connect me with?

Comment: The best thing for you to do right now is wait for sales to get back to you. They will get you connected to the right people for your use case.

Comment: What's the fastest way to getting in touch with thier sales team.

Comment: Sure thanks Phil. I got a work around from Kris which involves putting a twilio number as a muted participant and instructing it to indefinitely gather, however dialization is an issue there.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by “dialization” do you still need help with this?

Comment: Hey thanks Phil, I resolved this problem thanks to Kris. Will close the question, as the feature not available for public use right now.

Comment: I meant *diarization. coachParam enables hearing only the agent being coached which isn't enabled by default. WIthout coachParam the gathering inbound twilio number performs the real-time transcription of all the participants in the conference.

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks for explaining! Glad you know what's going on right now.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably late now. But, you can check out these apps if it helps -

Video Conferencing built using Twilio Video SDK with live captions - https://github.com/symblai/symbl-twilio-video-react

Twilio Media Streams Integration - https://github.com/symblai/symbl-twilio-media-streams-integration