# Unable to install twilio.AspNet mvc package

Tags: package, twilio

```
Install failed. Rolling back...
```

Install-Package : Could not install package 'Twilio.AspNet.Mvc 5.0.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets .NETFramework,Version=v4.5,
 but 
the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Twilio.AspNet.Mvc -Version 5.0.1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

Comment: You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework.

Comment: Per the requirements for the Twilio.AspNet.Mvc package, it does require .NET 4.5.1 or later. https://github.com/twilio/twilio-aspnet#requirements

Comment: @dprothero Spot on. Can you please share your thoughts on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54157444/real-time-transcription-twilio-agent-conference)

Comment: roberts thankyou for that already fixed

Comment: @dprothero Thanks

Answer (score 3):

1. Make sure that your Target Framework is at least 4.5.1
2. Use this command: Install-Package Twilio.AspNet.Mvc -DependencyVersion HighestMinor

Comment: This worked for me. I had v4.7.1 and was trying to install through GUI but doing same thing through Package Manager Console worked for me.