# Real time call transcription using twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-voice

At a higher level, I am trying to replicate what Kris showed in his demo here: https://youtu.be/Am74WU1zENA?t=717. This is the call flow I want to get to:

1. A customer calls in.
2. Customer gets automatically connected to an available agent
3. There is a webhook which shows the real time transcription of the call between the customer and the agent (preferably with speaker identification)

After browsing the twilio API docs and other stackoverflow threads (example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54157444/real-time-transcription-twilio-agent-conference)), it looks like the way to go about is to create a conference call between the agent and the customer along with a muted "supervisor" and then use the Gather verb for supervisor to listen to the conversation.
A few things I am confused about is:

1. How to automatically add the supervisor to the conference call whenever a new call comes in. I can manually add all the 3 participants to a conference room at the moment by using the Client.create method but wanted to know if there is better way to do this.
2. How to do speaker identification as gather just transcribe without identifying the speaker. Is there something like the dual-channel option in record, for gather.

Any pointers are appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

As discussed in [my answer and the following conversation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54196708/28376), the feature that Kris demonstrated is not available publicly. If you are interested in this feature, it's best to [get in touch with sales](https://www.twilio.com/help/sales) and register that you are interested in it.

`<Gather>` is not well suited to perform this sort of speech to text, it's best for responses from a single caller and [doesn't listen for longer than 60 seconds in speech mode](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather#input).